# Create new list in R based on matching values from two data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'),y=c(1,2,3,4,5))
df2<-data.frame(x=c('x3','x5'),y=c(3,5))

df3<-merge(df,df2,by="x")
```

How do I create a list of 0's and 1's based on if the x values from `df` were matched to the x values from `df2`? For example, the new data frame would look like:

`newdf<-data.frame(x=c('x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'),y=c(1,2,3,4,5),match=c(0,0,1,0,1)`

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` (matching on `x` and `y`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, match := 0L]
df[df2, on = .(x, y), match := 1L]
#     x y match
# 1: x1 1     0
# 2: x2 2     0
# 3: x3 3     1
# 4: x4 4     0
# 5: x5 5     1
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a similar problem, where now df2 is a list of data frames. Is there a way to match `df` to each data frame in the list and create a new column for each match?

Comment: You could use a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution to recreate your `newdf`:

```
newdf <- df
newdf$match <- ifelse(df$x %in% df2$x, 1, 0)
```

---

Or, using `tidyverse` syntax:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(match = ifelse(x %in% df2$x, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a similar problem, where now df2 is a list of data frames. Is there a way to match `df` to each data frame in the list and create a new column for each match?

Comment: Yes, that can be done too -- probably worth making a separate question with some reproducible sample data for it. The basic idea (if going the `base` or `tidyverse` approach) would be to run an `lapply()` over your list with an anonymous function inside that looks like the above, then to bind the rows together -- something like `lapply(mylist, function(y) {ifelse(df$x %in% y$x)})` followed by `rbind()` or something similar.